# How to use Tailwind Elements in Sveltekit

Tags: server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I'm trying to use a simple Tailwind [date picker](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/datepicker/) component in a svelte kit app, however the calendar popup is not appearing. I assume it has something to do with SRR. I was able to make some progress on the [installation](https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/) of Tailwind elements by importing the module with onMount():

```
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { browser } from '$app/env';

    onMount(async() => {
        if(browser) {
            await import('tw-elements');
        }
    });
```

However, the calendar icon and the popup are still not rendering. (They also do not render when I include the CDN in app.html). Is there a solution?

tailwind.config.js (P.S. [night wind](https://nightwindcss.com) works just fine):

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: "class",
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}', 
    './node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("nightwind"),
    require("tw-elements/dist/plugin")
  ],
}
```

Comment: It works when I add a delay, but this doesn't seem like a best practice. await setTimeout(() => {
                import('tw-elements');
            }, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

The docs are horrible, but it does work.  Here's how I got it going.

In your Svelte Kit layout, import CSS for tw-elements and Font awesome.  This is critical because the datepicker icon uses Font Awesome by default, and when you click the icon it opens the picker.

```js
import 'tw-elements/dist/css/index.min.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.min.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css'
```

```html
<div class="datepicker relative form-floating mb-3 xl:w-96">
    <input type="text" class="form-control block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
        placeholder="Select a date"/>
    <label for="floatingInput" class="text-gray-700">Select a date</label>
</div>
```

In Svelte onMount:

```js
// I didn't even need the if (browser) statement)
// import the library
onMount(async () => {
    await import('tw-elements/dist/src/js/index.js')
})
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like it is using the [MD Bootstrap Datepicker](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/datepicker) which is a premium feature of [MDB Pro](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/pro) and is not free.

Comment: The guy is using Tailwind Elements and you are referring to another library...

Comment: Have you tried it? Do it. (https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/datepicker/) Render the code into your front end and inspect it. The tw-elements datepicker is using mdb. Obviously the same guys made both, tw-elements seems to be their free version and mdb is the premium.

Comment: Not really relevant, as this can be solved by importing the free libraries and working it out as I did in my answer.